# Apply Css for elements even after postback-jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css

I have many  hrefs(with dynamic Ids) in my asp.net app that have the same CssClass=MyClass.

I want these button to be hidden with a condition.

I used the .ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(condition)
    $('.MyClass').css("display","none");
});
```

the problem is docuement.ready doesn't execut when there is a poctback.

Postback==>Button visible.normal as i've put the code in .ready.

Is there a way to persist the code:`$('.MyClass').css("display","none");`

I tried to apply `.live()` on button load,but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a different approach, define the style in CSS, like this:

```
body.conditionClass .MyClass { display: none; }
```

Then apply *that* class to `<body>` on `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(function() {
  if(condition)
    $('body').addClass('conditionClass');
});
```

Now new elements with `.MyClass`, anywhere in the `<body>` will get the `display: none` styling.

Comment: @amourgh - Yup, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZZmBg/ change the condition to `false` and hit run to see the opposite.

Comment: ya,your example works.I'm confused with this line:body.conditionClass .MyClass { display: none; } Where is the definition of MyClass .

Comment: @amourgh - It's from your example code in the question...whatever class you're currently using would be what you put in for `MyClass` .

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `livequery` plugin: http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

`live()` only binds events. When you have installed the plugin, use:

```
$('.MyClass') 
.livequery(function() { 
    $(this).css("display","none");
});
```

This will hide items of class `MyClass` whenever they are found, even if they are created from a Ajax response. You can even use this code in place of the `ready` function you are currently using.

In this case, Nick Craver's solution is better, but only if you have to evaluate `condition` just on page load.

Comment: If using `.livequery()`, you should use `this` inside, instead of the same selector ...but this is overkill for the situation :)

Comment: Ah, thank you; I just pasted that line and should have inspected it more carefully.

Comment: what i have done is:added  <script src="jquery.livequery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to my aspx.after i added the code of SimpleCoder.